# Angular - How to get angular directive to trigger after ng-click handler scope function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

**Scenraio**

I am pretty new to Angular and have the following issue.

I want to trigger a directive to change color and add an image on a button.  I can not get the first if condition to trigger this change in my Angular Directive.

**Problem**

I want to make the directive take action based on the result from ng-click handler.  Even though my debugger shows that directive is being called, I am not getting the first if condition to enter.

**Questions**

1) What do I need to do to get this to work?

2) Do I need to consider if ng-click is not called before the directive is handled?

**HTML**

```
<button class="email-reset-btn"  type="button" ng-click="resetEmailLink();" emailReset="changeBtn();" name="button">Email Reset Link</button>
```

**Scope Level Function**

```
var emailResetValidation = function () {
  if($('#email').val().trim() == "")
  {
    $(".email-reset-btn").removeClass("email-active-green");
  }
}
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('emailReset', [function(){
      return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.bind("click", function(){
            if(!elem.hasClass('email-active-green')) {  <--- Here is where I want the debugger to enter to change the button's HTML
               elem.html("<div class='email-sent-placeholder'><img width='15px' src='./resources/icons/icon_check@2x.png'/></div>&nbsp;<div class='email-reset-button-text'>Link Sent</div>");
            }
            else {
               elem.html("Email Reset Link");
            }
          })
        }
      });
```

Comment: Could you please share the html of #email ?

Comment: #email is just a text input whose id is "email"

Comment: I don't get the logic around when each of the buttons should show. And you are mixing angularjs with jQuery for the most basic thing as checking scope models. I've added a plunkr, which is a fork from QI.soa plunker, were you can see little small changes which makes angularjs awesome https://plnkr.co/edit/2fq3ndcN0XbOtiBDV4Kx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the `emailReset` directive.you should set the `email-reset` in your HTML like this

```
 <button class="email-reset-btn"  type="button" ng-click="resetEmailLink();" email-reset="changeBtn();" name="button">Email Reset Link</button>
```

and I can't understand what the `emailReset = "changeBtn()"` means?

try to see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mzv5A9PcU8uKXV3jxr67?p=preview)